# Transpose large numpy matrix on disk

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rust, transpose

I have a rather large rectangular (>1G rows, 1K columns) Fortran-style NumPy matrix, which I want to transpose to C-style.

So far, my approach has been relatively trivial with the following Rust snippet, using MMAPed slices of the source and destination matrix, where both `original_matrix` and `target_matrix` are MMAPPed [`PyArray2`](https://pyo3.github.io/rust-numpy/numpy/array/type.PyArray2.html), with [Rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/) handling the parallelization.

Since the `target_matrix` has to be modified by multiple threads, I wrap it in an [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html).

```rust
let shared_target_matrix = std::cell::UnsafeCell::new(target_matrix);

original_matrix.as_ref().par_chunks(number_of_nodes).enumerate().for_each(|(j, feature)|{
    feature.iter().copied().enumerate().for_each(|(i, feature_value)| unsafe {
        *(shared_target_matrix.uget_mut([i, j])) = feature_value;
    });
});
```

This approach transposes a matrix with shape (~1G, 100), ~120GB takes ~3 hours on an HDD disk. Transposing a (~1G, 1000), ~1200GB matrix does not scale linearly to 30 hours, as one may naively expect, but explode to several weeks. As it stands, I have managed to transpose roughly 100 features in 2 days, and it keeps slowing down.

There are several aspects, such as the employed file system, the HDD fragmentation, and how MMAPed handles page loading, which my solution is currently ignoring.

Are there known, more holistic solutions that take into account these issues?

### Note on sequential and parallel approaches

While intuitively, this sort of operation should be likely only limited by IO and therefore not benefit from any parallelization, we have observed experimentally that the parallel approach is indeed around three times faster (on a machine with 12 cores and 24 threads) than a sequential approach when transposing a matrix with shape (1G, 100). We are not sure why this is the case.

### Note on using two HDDs

We also experimented with using two devices, one providing the Fortran-style matrix and a second one where we write the target matrix. Both HDDs were connected through SATA cables directly to the computer motherboard. We expected at least a doubling of the performance, but they remained unchanged.

Comment: Given that the operation is probably limited by the speed of the HDD, I doubt that `rayon` helps here. In fact it may even slow things down by forcing more complex access patterns to the HDD, where a single thread program would have more regular (and hence faster) accesses.

Comment: Hi @Jmb! While that would also be my intuition, experiments testing a sequential and a parallel approach show that a parallel approach is roughly three times faster (on a machine with 24 threads). I have some rough ideas about why this may be the case, but I am not sure. 

I have added this observation to the question as it is pretty reasonable. It honestly left me baffled when I observed the opposite happening experimentally.

Comment: Efficient transposition algorithms are blocked such that the locality of the accesses is the best possible. This is true when transposing in memory (trying to avoid cache misses), and this is even more critical when transposing on disk (trying to avoid page faults). Is your method optimized for the locality of the accesses?

Comment: Why the parallel version is faster is maybe because the different threads tend to access data that are in the same pages in memory. If so, this would actually show that the access pattern of the method is quite bad in the first place. Regarding the non-linearity, there can be a threshold effect depending the amount of available RAM, again because of a poor access pattern: up to certain size, the OS can keep in RAM enough pages to mitigate a poor access pattern, and beyond that size it can no longer.

Answer (score 1):

> While intuitively, this sort of operation should be likely only limited by IO and therefore not benefit from any parallelization, we have observed experimentally that the parallel approach is indeed around three times faster

This may be due to poor IO queue utilization. With an entirely sequential workload without prefetching you'll be alternating the device between working and idle. If you keep multiple operations in flight it'll be working all the time.

Check with `iostat -x <interval>`

But parallelism is a suboptimal way to achieve best utilization of a HDD because it'll likely cause more head-seeks than necessary.

> We also experimented with using two devices, one providing the Fortran-style matrix and a second one where we write the target matrix. Both HDDs were connected through SATA cables directly to the computer motherboard. We expected at least a doubling of the performance, but they remained unchanged.

This may be due to the operating system's write cache which means it can batch writes very efficiently and you're mostly bottlenecked on reads. Again, check with `iostat`.

> There are several aspects, such as the employed file system, the HDD fragmentation, and how MMAPed handles page loading, which my solution is currently ignoring.
> Are there known, more holistic solutions that take into account these issues?

Yes, if the underlying filesystem supports it you can use [FIEMAP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/fiemap.txt) to get the physical layout of the data on disk and then optimize your read order to follow the physical layout rather than the logical layout. You can use the `filefrag` CLI tool to inspect the fragmentation data manually, but there are rust bindings for that ioctl so you can use it programmatically too.

Additionally you can use [`madvise(MADV_WILLNEED)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) to inform the kernel to prefetch data in the background for the next few loop iterations. For HDDs this should be ideally done in batches worth a few megabytes at a time. And the next batch should be issued when you're half-way through the current one.
Issuing them in batches minimizes syscall overhead and starting the next one half-way through ensures there's enough time left to actually complete the IO before you reach the end of the current one.

And since you'll be manually issuing prefetches in physical instead of logical order you can also disable the default readahead heuristics (which would be getting in the way) via `madvise(MADV_RANDOM)`

If you have enough free diskspace you could also try a simpler approach: defragmenting the file before operating on it. But even then you should still use madvise to ensure that there always are IO requests in flight.

Comment: I will start experimenting with these suggestions and extend the question accordingly. Many thanks!