# OpenMP column-major access to a large memory-mapped array is (sometimes) slow

Tags: c++, openmp, mmap, apple-silicon

I've got a large binary file of doubles, representing an array with 650000 rows and 10210 columns -- it takes up about 53 GB. We are using C `mmap` (via `<sys/mman.h>`) to access it.

Unfortunately, we need to operate on the array column-by-column.
If I run this in a single thread, it works fine, albeit a bit slow (typically 12-20 minutes depending on machine details).

To speed this up we have tried to use [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org) for threading. Sometimes it works fine. But sometimes accessing the file crawls to a halt. *With the exact same input, and the exact same OpenMP thread settings, the code can vary in speed by a factor of something like 500!* This is specifically an issue on an M1 Mac Studio with 20 cores. (I know that 4 of them are "efficiency" cores, but the problem occues even when using many fewer than the (OpenMP default) full complement of 20.)

I can imagine that their could be contention issues when different threads are trying to access very different parts of the memory-mapped file, but I don't know if this is actually what's going on. Any specific ideas?

For information, we are opening the file and creating the mapping with

```cpp
double* m_address = (double*)mmap(NULL, inputLength, PROT_READ, (MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE), m_filehandle, 0);
```

and, later, accessing it with

```cpp
int numColumns = 10210;
int numRows = 650000;
std::vector<double> thisColumn(numRows, 0.0);

#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(thisColumn)
for (unsigned int col=0; col<numColumns; ++col) {

    // the following is the slow bit...
    // read column col into thread-local thisSeries
    for (unsigned int row=0; row<numRows; ++row) {
        thisColumn[row] = m_address[size_t(row)*numColumns + col];
    }

    // process column col as thisColumn
}
```

Note that the inner loop is going through the array with a stride of `numColumns=10210`, so is jumping through the file from close to the beginning to close to the end for each value of `col`.

The bad behaviour seems to happen when compiled with either clang 14 or gcc/g++-13.

To be clear, the problem isn't a generic "cache miss" problem. Sometimes, it works fine, and shows reasonable speedups with moderate numbers of threads (from 1 to 8 or so) -- it is the brittleness of the setup, specifically when running with multiple threads, where the same setup can vary in execution time by two orders of magnitude!

Any ideas for what is really going on, and whether there are any good fixes? (And in particular why the behaviour varies so much with the same inputs?)

Comment: Lots of things are going on, you will have cache misses (hard to avoid with this much data). But I also suspect you will run into a lot of page faults (resulting in a lot of disk access). I think you need to find an algorithm the can work using smaller parts of your data and work your way up (even if in the end you need to do more work, the speedup in data acces (locality) may still be worth it. Then use threads to work on blocks of your matrix (step 1 keep each part in physical memory, 2nd try to keep each part in cache)

Comment: All in all I think this is a case where adding more threads may even harm perfomance becuase data access becomes even more random.

Comment: When the code is working properly, we actually see reasonable speedups from single threaded (about 19 minutes) down to 8 threads (about 4 minutes) but then it stops improving.  But sometimes it takes hours to run even with 4 threads.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that your access pattern is index 0, 10210, 20420, etc.? In that case you have abysmal locality: every single access is going to trigger a page fault. By the time you're done with a column, the start of the file will have been evicted from memory already and the next column is gonna fault on every access again. Is it at all feasible for you to do a one-time conversion on this file to flip rows and columns? Then you'd only need about 5MiB per column at any given time, and only every 2048th access should trigger a page fault.

Comment: Yes, access is jumping around a lot. But I am particularly confused about why runs with identical inputs can vary by a couple of orders of magnitude in time.

Comment: I have no explanation about the the erratic runtimes... Are you reading only the file, or are you also writing it?

Anyway, instead of reading and processing one column at a time, I would read chunks of columns (say 100 columns, they will easily fit into memory), and process a chunk before reading the next chunk. The access pattern on the file would be much better.

Comment: Doing strided access like this is *very inefficient*. You should *really* avoid this like the plague (especially on HDD but I assume you use a SSD). First, it tends to decrease the life of your SSD since cells that are read too many times tends to be relocated so to avoid a critical cell instability issues (writes are generally a much bigger issue but strided accesses like this cause the same cells to be read many many times). This relocation can also be the reason why you get unstable performance : an SSD can start relocating cells at any time regarding its internal state (like a GC).

Comment: Another possible issue could be a thermal throttling of the SSD. More threads means possibly more IOPS and a more saturated internal SSD chip (managing the IO requests) can reach a critical temperature (especially due to the non-contiguous pattern). Regarding how the OS implement the mapping, some pages of the RAM could be temporary stored on the SSD increasing the relocation issue and decreasing significantly the performance (this often happens on Linux for example). If you plan to read this file more than once, I strongly advise you to **transpose it first**. Is this Ok for you here?

Comment: On transposing large arrays on disk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73786879/transpose-large-numpy-matrix-on-disk

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I don't know anything about Rust, but it looks to me that the method shown in the linked question is a perfect example using high level and sophisticated features, but which are inefficient for the task. If I had to transpose from disk to disk I would use similar code to the one in my answer with "low level" old school loops to perform a transposition by blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the strided access to the file is highly ineffecient, and this may be even worse with multithreaded access.

Assuming you don't want to tranpose the whole file at once and create a new file, a compromise would be to decouple reading and processing: reading say 100 columns at a time, processing these columns, reading the next 100 columns, etc... This is actually transposing on the fly and by blocks. There is still some strided access to the file, but a part of the accesses are now sequential.

Only the processing part is multithreaded, as multithreading the reads would result in false sharing on the destination array.

There's a compromise to find for the chunk size: the larger the better for the performances, but the data have to fit into memory.

(not tested code)

```
int numColumns = 10210;
int numRows = 650000;
int chunk = 100;

std::vector<vector<double>> theseColumns[chunk];
for (int col=0; col<chunk; col++) theseColumns[col] = vector<double>[numRows];

for (int col1=0; col1 < numColumns; col1+=chunk) {

    // reading chunk columns in serial mode
    for (int row=0; row<numRows; ++row) {
        for (int col2=0; col2 < chunk && col1+col2 < numColumns; col2++) {
            theseColumns[col2][row] = m_address[size_t(row)*numColumns + col1 + col2];
        }
    }

    // processing the chunk columns in parallel
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (int col2=0; col2 < chunk && col1+col2 < numColumns; col2++) {
       // process theseColumns[col2]
   }

}
```

**Edit**: well, given the large number of rows, carefully multithreading the reads could actually be possible with minimal false sharing. Note that this makes sense only on a NVME SSD, as SATA SSDs don't really have parallel accesses, and this would even be catastrophic on a HDD.

Parallel version for the reads:

```
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int rowsPerThread = (numRows-1)/omp_get_num_threads() + 1;
        # pragma omp for schedule(static,rowsPerThread)
        for (int row=0; row<numRows; ++row) {
            for (int col2=0; col2 < chunk && col1+col2 < numColumns; col2++) {
                theseColumns[col2][row] = m_address[size_t(row)*numColumns + col1 + col2];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The combination presented here -- parallel *computations* on chunks of columns, with parallel *reading* over rows, seems to work well together at least on the one setup that I've tested (Mac Studio with M1 Max).

Comment: Detailed caveat: the `col1+col2 < numColumns` check is not allowed in the condition clause of the `for` loop, so those have to be moved into the loop bodies. This generally means that you will have some "no-op" loops at the end, but this is negligible.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot that. The other way is to precompute the actual number of iterations before the loop.